# Perl regex and < character

Tags: regex, perl, cgi

Been searching for answer to this, but no luck. Shamefully asking because I think I am missing something fundamental. This code is part of a HTML form+CGI script that uploads a file ,extracts it, and then displays information in HTML format from that uploaded file based on a form selection. This part is to create a list of .xml files in a directory called "mylogs" and then remove some of the path and add the characters to make it a valid HTTP link.

It runs up until `for (@array) {s/^/<a href="/};` and the less than character is causing the problem because if I remove it, it processes everything else. With the less than symbol included, it removes all output.

```
my $dir = "$upload_dir/var/mylogs";
my @array = <$dir/*.xml>;
for (@array) {s/\/volume1\/web//g};
for (@array) {s/^/http:\/\/192.168.1.155/g};
for (@array) {s/^/<a href="/g};
for (@array) {s/$/<a\/>/g};
```

I tried escaping the character as well but did not work either. Any ideas why it happens or a better way of accomplishing said end result?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The `<` has no special meaning in a regular expression, but it does have meaning in HTML.  If you are only viewing the output in a web browser, then you won't see anything because the tag isn't terminated properly, as explained by @Adrian Pronk.  View Source or run the script in a terminal to see what you're actually generating as output.

Answer (score 4):

You're not closing off your  tag properly (and no need to use `/g` modifier when replacing `^` or `$`):

```
$_ = '/foo';
s/^/http:\/\/192.168.1.155/;   
  # Result is: http://192.168.1.155/foo
s/^/<a href="/;
  # Result is: <a href="http://192.168.1.155/foo
s/$/<a\/>/;
  # Result is: <a href="http://192.168.1.155/foo<a/>
  # Should be: <a href="http://192.168.1.155/foo"> What do you want here? </a>
```

Did you actually look at the source of the HTML you produced?

Answer (score 2):

You have not demonstrated your problem, and the claims you make are false.

```
$ perl -E'
   my @array = qw( foo bar );
   for (@array) {s/^/<a href="/g};
   say for @array;
'
<a href="foo
<a href="bar
```